# Can a short circuit damage nearby devices?

Tags: basic

This happened yesterday and left me scratching my head.

We had a badly built power extension cord in our office. Inside it has 3 wires - live, zero and ground (hope I got the terminology right). When plugging in a phone charger, the live wire touched the ground wire and blew a fuse. However it appears that a notebook power supply that was already plugged in the same extension cord was also damaged. Now, when plugging in that notebook charger (anywhere), it too blows a fuse.

What I'm wondering is - how could this happen? As per my understanding of electricity, the live wire touching the ground wire should simply cut the power to the notebook power supply, since all the current would now flow from the live wire to the ground wire and away. There should be no high voltages produced in the nearby devices. Is there any other mechanism as to how this could have happened?

Comment: There are many ways how this could have happened, including coincidence, this isn't really the right place to speculate around.

Comment: Only someone (an EE perhaps) who understands how all involved devices work, is **on site**, can dismantle and investigate any device involved or suspect, maybe even has a lab with specialist instruments available, has time and money to do all this, could do an investigation, then **maybe** this person would reach a conclusion. A conclusion which you might not understand because you're not an EE. So why do you need to understand this? What would that bring you? Next time, get your power extensions build **properly**. Why increase the chance of your house burning down?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Nobody can tell you what happened, but here is one speculation. Any time you change the current rapidly, (start OR stop it) an inductive component can generate spikes of very high voltage - not AC mains but much higher. See Lenz's Law. These spikes can destroy electronic components like diodes.  And there were inductive components (transformers) and diodes in what used to be your power supply. In normal use, designers can protect against these spikes, but short circuiting live mains is not normal use.

Comment: Well, I'm no EE, but I have tinkered with electricity a bit and I do have a basic understanding of what is what. Also, I assumed that this wouldn't be a speculation but rather that there is a definitive answer to my question (either "<insert mechanism here>" or "coincidence"). But if you say there are multiple ways and this question is a poor choice for this site, then OK - I can delete it. Alternatively, if someone writes an answer, I'll accept it. Lenz's Law seems good.

Comment: I suggest you read Brian Drummond's comment.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf - Umm, I did. What makes you think I didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't know what was going on when the power was shorted out, the charger could have been causing an over-voltage condition on the line and that could have blown out the notebook power supply.

Or the charger could have been injecting current into the ground and the preferred pathway could have been through an improperly built notebook power supply (of chinese manufacture without ETL testing).

There is no way to really tell what when on without schematics for both power supplies and how the cable was miswired.

> Can a short circuit damage nearby devices?

Apparently, yes through your account of the damaged charger, it can

Comment: Well, it could also be pure coincidence. :) Also, for the miswire, we already identified that - the ground touched the live wire inside the extension cord socket. Neither charger had anything directly to do with the short circuit (well, not electrically, anyway).